# How to change the ImageButton image in baseAdapter when clicking that ImageButton

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am trying to change the ImageButton image.ImageButton in listView CustomAdapter.When Clicking that ImageButton change the image of that ImageButton.I trying like this.But is not working.

```
private int[] mIcons = { R.drawable.like_grey, R.drawable.dislike_grey };
private int[] mSelectedIcons = { R.drawable.like_selected, R.drawable.dislike_selected};

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.moments_custom_screen, null);
            holder.mLikeBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_btn);
            holder.mDisLikeBtn =(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dislike_btn); 
            holder.mLikeBtn.setImageResource(mIcons[0]);
            holder.mDisLikeBtn.setImageResource(mIcons[1]);

            holder.mLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.mLikeBtn.setImageResource(mSelectedIcons[0]);
                holder.mDisLikeBtn.setClickable(true);
            }
        });

           holder.mDisLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.mLikeBtn.setImageResource(mIcons[0]);
                holder.mDisLikeBtn.setImageResource(mSelectedIcons[1]);
                holder.mDisLikeBtn.setClickable(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Remove call to notifyDataSetChanged() in your onClickListener.

Comment: Ya removed but no change.